# How to keep Mac alive during internet connection/download

Tags: macos, wifi, power-management

Since OS X version 10.8.1, my Mac cancels the wifi connection and switches to standby mode, despite having an active download.

I can remember that the one advantage of the Mac was that I didn't have to do anything for that. The Mac stayed awake during downloads, so I could leave the house and if the download is finished, it would switch to standby mode.

But now, it activates standby despite downloading.

Here are my energy save options:

[image: energy options]

Is this a bug? How can I keep my Mac from going into standby mode while downloading?

I have Mountain Lion installed (10.8.3).

Comment: Transmission has an option to not allow the computer sleep when downloading. Probably there is some code/information it could reference to.

Comment: What app is performing the downloads?

Answer (score 2):

[Caffeine](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/caffeine/id411246225?mt=12) is a nice tool that prevents your mac from sleeping / going to stand-by.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may not be a question of power, but badly configured wifi.

You may try to follow these instructions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47241/my-macbook-pro-loses-its-connection-to-my-wifi-router?rq=1).

Comment: If those don't work, try to downgrade the security level. First, use no wifi protection, and see if problem persists. Than raise it to WEP, WPA, WPA2. Try to use 802g also.

Comment: I have the same router which i used for my iMac 2010, and now with my iMac 2012. With OS X Lion, there was no Problem (iMac 2010), but now with Mountain Lion, it disconnects from the WiFi. I don't think thats a configuration problem.

Comment: That may be an issue with your iMac 2012 wireless card then… Anyway, double check the configurations when you have time and patience to do so. I did this scheme of raising the security just to check if it was my card, and surprisingly when I put without security it wouldn't drop. In the end I set it to use until WPA2 802g, but I couldn't use the 802n. And this was ok when I used the Snow Leopard.